# problem when installing RTextTools for R

Tags: r

I was trying to install RTextTools package for R, but failed. Here is the output from the screen

```
> >  install.packages("RTextTools")
Warning in install.packages("RTextTools") :
  argument 'lib' is missing: using 'C:\Users\datamining\Documents/R/win-library/2.10'
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/2.10
Warning message:
In getDependencies(pkgs, dependencies, available, lib) :
  package ‘RTextTools’ is not available
```

What's the reason for this problem, and how to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two distinct, but related, issues:

- You are running version 2.10 of R which is two years old.   CRAN supports only the current version with pre-built binaries. You could try installing from source.
- RTextTools, as can be seen on [its CRAN page](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RTextTools/index.html) also requires at least R version 2.13.

So in short: you should upgrade.

Comment: package 'RTextTools' is not available (for R version 3.5.3)

Comment: You commented on an answer that is more than seven years old.  Sometimes packages change, sometimes they get removed.  Such is life.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the issue. I have Download RTextTools From Given Link. 
 `https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RTextTools/`
and copy `RTextTools_1.4.2.tar.gz` file in project root folder then run this command in project folder in terminal

`"R CMD INSTALL RTextTools_1.4.2.tar.gz"`

After running this command I receive below error

"ERROR: dependencies `‘SparseM’`, `‘randomForest’`, `‘tree’`, `‘e1071’`, `‘ipred’`, `‘caTools’`, `‘maxent’`, `‘glmnet’`, `‘tau’` are not available for package `‘RTextTools’`".

Now install each dependencies from RStudio or RConsole (Any Editor used by you) by simply running this code.

`install.packages("caTools")`.

Install all 9 required packages One By One (In My Case it was 9 Packages Dependencies required by `RTextTools`) all packages will be installed except `'maxent'`.

Now download maxent from the given link.

`https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/maxent/`.

and copy `maxent_1.3.3.1.tar` file in project folder then run this command in project folder in terminal.

`"R CMD INSTALL maxent_1.3.3.1.tar"`

Now For `RTextTools` Run this command again in Terminal.

`"R CMD INSTALL RTextTools_1.4.2.tar.gz"`

All is done Now..
But the Last Step is
Load the `RTextTools` using.

`library(RTextTools)`

You will see one more Error: Load SparseM Now Loading SparseM use code below.

`library(SparseM)`

and in the last Load `RTextTools`

`library(RTextTools)`

Answer (score 0):

RTextTools is dependent on a number of packages, most of which require R 2.13+. You should always keep R updated to the latest version, since each update contains numerous bug fixes and performance enhancements.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't install packages from repository or the packages are not available anymore, just follow this steps:

1. Install.packages("devtools")
2. check -- library("devtools")
3. install_github("cran/maxent")
4. install_github("cran/RTextTools")